# SQL Query to Update One Table if Value Matches in Another

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join

I am having trouble writing an SQL query which I am trying to do using an Update and Join. I have already checked online here and there are numerous similar examples but I haven't been able to get them to work as yet.

I am trying to do a join between Table A and Table B (on a unique id linking them) and then update a value in Table A, if two of the values found in Table B match what what I am expecting (which I am inputting manually in the statement):

```
UPDATE TableA 
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.UniqueId = TableB.UniqueId 
SET TableA.email = 'emailaddress' 
WHERE upper(TableA.user) = upper('user') AND TableB.Account = 'accountnumber' 
      AND TableB.userType = 'usertype';
```

I may be over complicating this. Thanks.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  Your syntax is not supported by most databases.  And please explain what the issue is with your query.  It does not look overly complicated given what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use merge

```
MERGE INTO TableA e
USING (SELECT * FROM TableB) h
ON (e.UniqueId = h.UniqueId)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
     SET e.email = 'emailaddress'
   WHERE upper(e.user) = upper('user')
     AND h.Account = 'accountnumber'
     AND h.userType = 'usertype';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
UPDATE TableA 
SET TableA.email='emailaddress' 
FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB 
ON TableA.UniqueId = TableB.UniqueId
WHERE upper(TableA.user) = upper('user') 
AND TableB.Account = 'accountnumber' 
AND TableB.userType = 'usertype';
```

Comment: That's non-standard SQL. You should add for which DBMS this works

Comment: Apologies, this is using an Oracle Database

Comment: sorry i didn't get you, do u need a query that runs on oracle database or what?